# unexpected lines on CustomPaint

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-custompainter

I am using [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) to draw some rectangle. But there are visible lines inside my canvas.

**Current output**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

**Code to reproduce the issue**

```dart
void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: CustomPaintIssue()));

class CustomPaintIssue extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPaintIssue({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: MyPainter(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    const div = 34;
    Size blocSize = Size(size.width / div, size.height / div);

    for (int i = 0; i < div; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < div; j++) {
        canvas.drawRect(
          Rect.fromLTWH(
            i * blocSize.width,
            j * blocSize.height,
            blocSize.width,
            blocSize.height,
          ),
          Paint()
            ..color = Colors.red
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

> Instead of extending rect size, there should be better explanation for this type of behavior, that is what I am looking for and how to overcome this situation.

Flutter 3.0.1 & Dart 2.17.1

Comment: you cannot avoid this, sorry

Comment: @pskink thanks for the comment, Is it a bug then?

Comment: no, basically you don't draw on pixel boundaries, if you want to draw red rect 2.5 X 2.5 then four pixels will be red, but 2 pixels on the right side and 2 pixels on the bottom side will be 0x80ff0000 and the bottom-right pixel will have even different color

Comment: @MatiasLappalainen nope, I've changed the design and extend the width & height by 1px for each bloc

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Thank you! Adding 1 pixel to the width and height seems to fix the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is if you divide 500 by 34 you get 14.7058823529 and multipluing this with 34 will give 499.99999 which is not 500. Hence each block has a very small space. To overcome this you can either divide it witha number like 25 or 20 which will not end up in a decimal value or give a background color for the container that holds this custom paint

[image: preview1]

[image: preview2]

[image: preview3]

Comment: I've tested div with 20 and 25, still visible lines. Also,  1st rect end point is second rect start point, even if I've some space, shouldn't it be only on the right side?

Comment: Try with 50 or 10.. I just did..

Comment: Still get visible lines on, btw tested device is chrome

Comment: Edited my answer with 3 values, 50, 10 and 23.

Comment: Did you test on chrome ?  Also, why available space doesn't shift on right side

Comment: Yes tested now with chrome.. gave same results for me on chrome But using flutter run -d web-server